# Why is this code rounding small decimals to 1 or 0 when trying to follow mouse position?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am trying to drag a triangle around my screen with the mouse using the following procedure: (When the mouse is pressed, redraw is true, factor is 0.01, offset is just 8 pixels to account for the whitespace next to the canvas, I know that is not what's causing the issue)

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
    if(redraw) {
        newX = event.clientX - offSet;
        dx = factor * (newX - prevX);
        prevX = newX;
    }
});
```

However, when I log my dx, it is always an integer, never the smallish decimal I am expecting and hoping for.

Comment: Could you provide a link with this code? I mean full code. I ran it on my machine, dx is a float.

Comment: There's nothing definitely wrong in the code you're showing. You need to show _code which could be run to reproduce the problem_ — see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .